# CKEditor after copy+pasting URL, new text on next line is blue and underlined

Tags: ckeditor

We use CKEditor with auto-link-plugin to make URLs clickable.

After copy+pasting the URL, the link is blue and underlined: nice.

Unfortunately new text on the next lines is blue and underlined, too.

Is there a way to disable this?

Comment: This is a common behavior of most of the editors, even in ms-office also. we have to explicitly change the font properties to make it normal after copying the text from some where and paste.

Comment: @KamalGadepalli the strange thing: sometimes it works, sometime not. Up to now I  could not determine the reason why.

Comment: Can you handle the paste ? Otherwise you can set your font style/model to default after each paste

Comment: @AntoinePointeau up to now I did not change the handling of paste in CKEditor.

Comment: @guettli can you please add a bit more info? What exact text do you copy (where from)? How do you paste (ctrl+v or mouse-right click)? Which versions of the ckeditor & auto-link-plugin you use? Thanks!

Comment: @guettli is this question still relevant? Without more information it's really hard to help. Thanks!

Comment: @guettli not best solution but had issue like this with inline and bootstrap. only way got to work was complete paragraph then come back and paste in links. never figured out cause. just adapted...

Comment: @guettli, I just downloaded the latest version of CKE and with the same plugin. I don't face the issue. See this [video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TYd7.gif)

Comment: @guettli, did you get a chance to look at gif I posted in the comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a solution, but a work-around for the end-user of CKEditor.

There is an unlink button: [image: unlink-icon]

If you click on it, then the next text you type won't be part of the link.

Unfortunately after clicking the button the cursor is still blinking in blue color. But if you start to type, it gets black (relieve).

Answer (score 1):

It is common behavior with most of the editors. Before pasting any link give an extra space, and use left arrow to come back to right place and paste link and use right arrow to move extra space and continue. See if this helps.

Comment: Yes, I have seen the same behaviour in Thunderbird, too. Still I think this is an usability thing which should be solved. Your suggestion works, but wouldn't it be great if the suggestion is needed at all?

Comment: This work around is ok if you are a geek. For average users it too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a paragraph to place in the link, paste the link and then move to the next paragraph. This means you will have to create to paragraphs in the beginning. First one for the link and the second to continue your typing